framer motion detect what image is in view of an infinite scroll
If someone could give me some advice on this problem I have spent a long time on.
There is an example here
You might have to refresh the app to see the animation running.  Using the refresh button shown in the image below:

I animate a series of divs using framer-motion . You'll see the red divs infintely scroll across the view.
Below the animated images (line 178 in the code) is a component that renders buttons , one for each giv in the animation. It is passed the activeIndex which initially is set to 0. This applies some css styling to that button in the component.
However when the animation runs I do not see how to update the index when an image enters the view , using setIndex.
How would I be able to get the index or id of an  div when it enters the animation and use that to update the index to update the 'Dot' component.
I hope that is clear.  Thanks for any thoughts, I've loode all over and haven't seen how to do it.

Can you make a reproducible example of what you have in https://playcode.io/react or https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-new?

I'll try to get something done, But eally the question is given you are using framer-motion to animate a list of images , is there anyway to get the curently animated image details

I have added something from code sandbox as a example

Hi! Did you delete? I am getting a "sandbox not found"

Thanks for your comment , I can access it via the link .I'll look into it. Once again I appreciate you trying to help

My apologies I didn't make it public.

I think I was able to kind of achieve the behavior you wanted:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-leavitt-5nf4fy
It's basically a crazy logic to set the active based on how much the container is dragged:
  useMotionValueEvent(dragX, "change", (latest) => {
    const index = parseInt((1100 + latest) / 350);
    const invertedIndex = Math.abs(6 - index);
    setImgIndex(invertedIndex);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setImgIndex(INITIAL_INDEX);
    let controls = animate(dragX, [0, -1100, 1100, 0], {
      ease: "linear",
      duration: 20,
      repeat: Infinity,
      repeatType: "loop",
      repeatDelay: 0,
    });

    return controls?.stop;
  }, []);

But I really don't recommend it, for the behavior you want, you will have much better luck using a carousel, you can search for some examples of react carousel in google.

In the end I went for react-slick. This has an api for the developer to access what slide is being animated.

Cool! Seems good

Actually do yourselves a favour if you want a carousel and use embla carousel. It is much better https://www.embla-carousel.com/
